# Combining multiple lines into a single based on column values

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file with below records.

```
$File.txt
APPLE,A,10
APPLE,A,20
APPLE,A,30
GRAPE,B,12
GRAPE,B,13
```

I want the output to be as given below:

```
  APPLE,A,10|20|30,
  GRAPE,B,12|13,
```

I have tried the below method and got the required output. But looking for something simpler.

```
awk -F"," '{if(NR<2){if(!seen[$1]++){printf "%-8s|",$3}}else{if(seen[$1]++){printf "%-12s|",$3}else{ printf ",\n%-12s|",$3}}}' File1.txt  | awk -F"|" '{for(i=1;i<NF-1;i++){ printf "%-12s|",$i}printf "%-12s,\n", $(NF-1)}'|sed 's/ //g' > O1.txt
awk -F"," '{print $1","$2","}' File1.txt | uniq > O2.txt
paste -d'\0' O2.txt O1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Inian

Comment: `datamash -t, -g1,2 collapse 3 <File.txt` would have suited well here, but as far as I know it doesn't allow to specify the separator to use for collapsing :-/ `datamash -t, -g1,2 collapse 3 <ip.txt | sed 's/,/|/3g'` can be used with GNU sed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
$ awk -F, '{k=$1 FS $2; a[k]=((k in a)?a[k]"|":k FS)$3} 
       END {for(k in a) print a[k] FS}' file

APPLE,A,10|20|30,
GRAPE,B,12|13,
```

to remove the last comma, remove the `FS` in print statement. If your file is already sorted this can be simplified further.

Comment: I need the last ,. Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 1):

You need something like below with just standalone `awk`

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS }{ key = $1","$2 }{ unique[key] = unique[key]?(unique[key]"|"$3):($3) }
         END { for (i in unique) print i, unique[i] }' file
```

If you think you need the extra `,` at the end just add `","` at the `END` clause after printing the elements from the array.

Comment: here `","` is `FS`